# How to define a default sorting in a Sulu admin list view

Tags: sulu

I have created a REST controller for a custom entity that should be administrated by the backend of the [Sulu CMS](https://sulu.io/). My implementation is analog to this [example](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/pull/84/files#diff-ef0fc32f0f4dbb24af157d8f10f38ab9faac9fbc41e61115ee7d260dbc4a4a1a).

Now I want to define a default sorting at the list view. Currently the items are listed just like they are fetched from the database. Of course the user can sort it in the frontend.

But I want to order the list per default by the entities *name* attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the listBuilder with fieldDescriptors you can do something like this:

```
$fieldDescriptors = $this->fieldDescriptorFactory->getFieldDescriptors('your_list');

// ....

if (!$request->query->get('sortBy')) { // set default sorting when no sorting is given
    $listBuilder->sort($fieldDescriptors['created'], 'desc');
}
```